# Fixing waits in Protractor 2.0 with ExpectedCondition

Tags: angularjs, protractor

Due to Protractor 2.0's breaking changes, I have to refactor my `at()` function. I use this on non-angular pages to both wait for the page to load, and return true, so it's expectable (if that's a word).

Because 2.0 no longer returns a promise from a locator, it's breaking my wait (wait fires immediately). Thus, I've turned to the new ExpectedConditions... which works fine. **My question is, am I using this correctly, or is there a better solution?**

Page object locator:

```
this.pageLoaded = $('div#splash[style="display: none;"]');
```

Works in Protractor 1.8.0 (breaks in 2.0.0):

```
this.at = function() {
    var that = this;
    return browser.wait(function() {
        return browser.isElementPresent(that.pageLoaded);
    });
};
```

My working solution for Protractor 2.0.0:

```
this.at = function() {
    var that = this;
    return browser.wait(function() {
        return protractor.ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(that.pageLoaded);
    });
};
```

And for example, I would call this like so:

```
expect(mainPage.at()).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Ultimately, I'll be putting the ExpectedCondition in the pageLoaded locator itself; to add flexibility on how a page load is represented (especially when using and/or/not!). But this example was a bit more apples to apples...

Comment: As @Ryan Gross mentioned the default timeout changed as well. And I think in your case this causes the main problem. 
And this comment can be interesting as well: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2253#issuecomment-116851881

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there was another breaking change in the [Protractor 2.0 changelog](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), referring to a problem in WebDriver 2.45 that makes the wait parameter required:

> Due to changes in WebDriverJS, wait without a timeout will now default to waiting for 0 ms instead of waiting indefinitely.
>
> Before:
>
> browser.wait(fn); // would wait indefinitely
>
> After:
>
> browser.wait(fn, 8000) // to fix, add an explicit timeout
>
> This will be reverted in the next version of WebDriverJS.

In our Protractor tests, we always refer to a common helper class `var helper = require("..\helpers.scenario.js")`.  To fix this problem, we just wrapped browser.wait in the helper class and passed in a timeout.

```
wait: function(f) {
    return browser.wait(f, 30000);
},
```

We then used find-replace to change from `browser.wait` to `helper.wait`.